# Django charfield choices compatibility

Tags: django, django-models

I've a model which has field choices. In the saving case i wanna make sure that value is in that choices list.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

But when i try to save with value out of choices , it saves that value.

```
      foo = Foo(gender = "A")                      
      foo.save()
```

Yes i can control it in code like `if value in genderlist:` but in my project that will take so time to add this control in every usage of choices saves. **Is there any chance to control it in MODEL ( overriding save method or some option for field or etc ) ?**

Comment: If you use a Django `ModelForm` the form will reject this.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes i can control it in code like if value in genderlist: but in my project that will take so time to add this control in every usage of choices saves.

The choices are indeed *not* enforced at the database level, and Django's models do not validate data before saving it for performance reasons.

If you can call `.full_clean()` to validate the model objects, so if you call `foo.full_clean()` we get:

```
>>> foo.full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "djtest/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1238, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'gender': ["Value 'A' is not a valid choice."]}
```

If you work with a `ModelForm`, it will also result in an invalid form if the the value is not one of the choices. Usually it is better to work with a (`Model`)`Form` to retrieve data since such forms can return all the errors and remove a lot of boilerplate code.